# Using Ticks in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I'd like to preface with the fact that I never actually learned how to properly code with Netlogo, everything I've done has been through trial and error and asking questions here when I got stuck. So if this is a stupid question, I apologize!

I'm currently working on a model in which every tick equals one day. I have a specific action that I want to occur at specific ticks (when ticks = 60, 425, 790, 1155, 1520, 1855, etc).

I tried this:

```
 if ticks = [60 425 790 1155 1520 1885]


 [
    create-hatchlings Hatchling-Release
    [ set color 57
    set size 1.5
    move-to one-of patches with [ pcolor = cyan ]
    set birth-tick -60]

 create-m-hatchlings Hatchling-Release
    [ set color 107
    set size 1.5
    move-to one-of patches with [ pcolor = cyan ]
    set m-birth-tick -60]
  ]
```

With this code, the nothing happens. The only way I'm able to get the event to happen at the right time is by writing it separately for each number, like so:

```
if ticks = 60
  [
    create-hatchlings Hatchling-Release
    [ set color 57
    set size 1.5
    move-to one-of patches with [ pcolor = cyan ]
    set birth-tick -60]

 create-m-hatchlings Hatchling-Release
    [ set color 107
    set size 1.5
    move-to one-of patches with [ pcolor = cyan ]
    set m-birth-tick -60]
  ]

 if ticks = 425
  [
    create-hatchlings Hatchling-Release
    [ set color 57
    set size 1.5
    move-to one-of patches with [ pcolor = cyan ]
    set birth-tick -60]

 create-m-hatchlings Hatchling-Release
    [ set color 107
    set size 1.5
    move-to one-of patches with [ pcolor = cyan ]
    set m-birth-tick -60]
  ]
```

but I would eventually have to do this hundreds of times. Is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `member?` to check if the tick value appears in your list:

```
if member? ticks [60 425 790 1155 1520 1885]
[
  ; do something 
]
```

On the other hand - if you want to do something on the 60th day every year, use modulo (`mod`):

```
if ticks mod 365 = 60
[
  ; do something 
]
```

So you don't need the list.